# Getting a count of Documents (Rows) using mapReduce in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, count, mapreduce, database

I hate to re-post this stuff but i feel as though I've typed exactly the same syntax as most of the issues I've looked up. I'm trying to simply map down a count of how many rows there are with a price greater than 9000. Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
var map1 = function(){
    if(this.price > 9000) {
        emit(this._id, {count: 1});
    }
};

var red1 = function(keyId, values){
    var count = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) {
            count +=v['count'];
            });

    return{count: count};
}

db.plots.mapReduce(map1, red1, {out: "query1"})
```

My results end up like this...

```
> db.query1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906815"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906816"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90681c"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906834"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90683e"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906846"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90684b"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90684e"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906851"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90685a"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906861"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906864"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906879"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906882"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906883"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90688b"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90688c"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906891"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc906894"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5170609afa9e8646fc90689a"), "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
```

What I would like is to just get a single number back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong - you are emitting a unique key per document: since reduce combines all documents with the same key you are getting no aggregations, you are also comparing each value to 9000 instead of using the query option to map/reduce.

I'm not sure why you are using map/reduce - this is very simple with aggregation framework:

```
db.plots.aggregate([ {$match:{price:{$gt:9000}}}, 
                     {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
] );
```

If you have some reason to do this with map reduce I recommend the following:

```
map = function() { emit(1, 1); }
reduce = function( key, values ) {
    var count = 0;
    values.forEach(function(v) {
            count +=v;
    });

    return count;
}

db.plots.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "query1", query:{price:{$gt:9000}}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This cleared up a lot. Does emit(1, 1); force the mapReduce to use my entire collection as the values? And i'm assuming when you group where _id:null it "groups" everything individually?

Comment: basically whether you emit 1 or null or "foo" it doesn't matter in map reduce or in aggregation - it just says sum grouping by "constant" rather than by value of a field.